# Cannot use .c file in Android NDK project

Tags: android-ndk

If I have my Android NDK project use a .c file instead of .cpp I cannot resolve any functions inside JNIEnv*. Here is how I'm trying to use it:

```
(*env)->GetCharArrayElements(chrs, 0);
```

I have also tried:

```
GetCharArrayElements(env, chrs, 0);
env->GetCharArrayElements(chrs, 0);
```

This is getting frustrating as I have some c library projects that I would like to include but if I have .cpp file then the library will need to be ported somehow and I would like to avoid that. Any help/ideas would be great.

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NDKDemo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NDKDemo.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**edit:**

Here is how I'm declaring JNIEnv*

```
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_atd_ndkdemo_NDKDemo_charManip(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jcharArray chrs) 

    jchar* cchar0 = GetCharArrayElements(chrs, 0);
    jchar* cchar1 = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, chrs, 0);
    jchar* cchar2 = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(chrs, 0);
    jchar* cchar3 = env->GetCharArrayElements(chrs, 0);
}
```

Interestingly, **cchar0** doesn't complain until I try to compile, then eclipse tells me it cannot be resolved again.

Comment: Try `(*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, chrs, 0)`.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Method GetCharArrayElements cannot be resolved

Comment: Maybe `env` has the wrong type?  How is the method declared?

Comment: added an update to original post

Comment: I'm also getting  undefined reference to 'GetCharArrayElements', so cchar0 seems to be right, just for some reason it is undefined/ not being linked?

Comment: Take a look at a copy of jni.h (say, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/gingerbread/libnativehelper/include/nativehelper/jni.h).  Note that GetCharArrayElements is a member of a struct.  The fact that you are able to find it globally makes me wonder if there's a `#define` somewhere that is messing things up.  There should be no GetCharArrayElements function visible to the NDK linker -- it's only accessible as a member of the struct.

Comment: Okay this is really weird. I just reinstalled NDK plugin for eclipse and NDK and am using cchar1. The errors still come up saying Method 'GetCharArrayElements' could not be resolved but it compiles. I still can't run the whole project becuase it thinks there are errors

Comment: Note re-asked -- and answered -- in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608634/weird-jni-ndk-behavior-in-eclipse-3-8