# Weird JNI/NDK behavior in eclipse 3.8

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am unable to use .c files in my NDK projects within eclipse 3.8. Consider the following code:

```
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_atd_ndkdemo_NDKDemo_charManip(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jcharArray chrs) 

    jchar* cchar0 = GetCharArrayElements(chrs, 0);
    jchar* cchar1 = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, chrs, 0);
}
```

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NDKDemo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NDKDemo.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**cchar0** doesn't complain until I compile, then I get a method undefined

**cchar1** complains before I compile, but is able to compile (if i omit cchar0). I get a method undefined or not part of struct or something similar.

This has me baffled. I have completely reinstalled eclipse/jni/ndk plugin and still same issue. There is a little bug icon next to cchar1 on the left where I set breakpoints if that helps. Also, I have not modified jni.h or any other files. It is important that I leave my file as .c.

**edit**

Method 'GetCharArrayElements' could not be resolved

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7O51.png

Screenshot to build success: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbXAK.png

Comment: You'd better paste the compile error messages. The error message is `error: 'const struct JNINativeInterface' has no member named 'GetCharArrayElements'` for cchar1, right?

Comment: updated my original post to show original error message and screenshot of error&build success

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23158929/629118 ?

Comment: thank you! this did the trick. I can't believe that the NDK plugin for eclipse doesn't do this though.